# how to assign variable value in python in terminal commands?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

My code:

```
import os
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("jobs.xml")

job = doc.getElementsByTagName("job")[0]
id = job.getElementsByTagName("id")[0]
name = job.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]

id_data = id.firstChild.data
name_data = name.firstChild.data

os.system('curl --compressed -H "Accept: application/xml" -X GET "http://localhost:19888/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/"')
>>> /home/ankit/rrd-xml/task.xml
```

I want to get the commands like

```
os.system('curl --compressed -H "Accept: application/xml" -X GET "http://localhost:19888/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/< variable value of name_data >"') 
>>> /home/ankit/rrd-xml/task.xml
```

How can i do it in python itself?

Comment: What do you mean with *I want to get the commands like...*? It's not clear what you're asking. Do you meant the output of that call? Or the process ID of the spawned process, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a simple *string formatting*.

```
import os
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("jobs.xml")

job = doc.getElementsByTagName("job")[0]
id = job.getElementsByTagName("id")[0]
name = job.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]

id_data = id.firstChild.data
name_data = name.firstChild.data

url = 'http://localhost:19888/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/{name}'.format(name=name_data)
cmd = 'curl --compressed -H "Accept: application/xml" -X GET "{url}"'.format(url=url)

os.system(cmd)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes around the command, or even triple quotes, so that the quotes that form part of the command are not confused with the Python string:

```
os.system('curl --compressed -H "Accept: application/xml" -X GET "http://localhost:19888/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/{}" >> /home/ankit/rrd-xml/task.xml'.format(name_data))
```

That will work, but it's not the best. It would be better for you to use Python to make the HTTP request. [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) is a good module for this:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:19888/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/{}'.format(name_data)
headers = {'Accept': 'application/xml'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

with open('/home/ankit/rrd-xml/task.xml', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(response.content)
```

This code will GET the URL, setting the `Accept` header to `application/xml` and append the response to the file. Compression is requested by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess`. The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using the `os.system` function.

```
import subprocess
import shlex

command = shlex.split('curl --compressed -H "Accept: application/xml" -X GET http://localhost:19888/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/')

with open('/home/ankit/rrd-xml/task.xml', 'a') as f:
    subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=f)
```

Comment: This won't work as is. You might want to split the command up into a list. Or, because of the redirection, set `shell=True` and hope that it is not insecure.

Comment: That's still not going to work. For one thing, `split()` will split the header. `shlex.split()` might be better. Also, the IO redirection will not work. Either you need to open the output file and pass it to `Popen` as the child's stdout; or do not split the command string, set `shell=True` and open up a potential security risk.

Comment: @mhawke thanks for that mate. Very useful info there. I wish I could upvote your comments but sadly I don't have enough points to do so. Cheers!